# AWS CodeBuild Error while copying file from S3 - COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Reason: exit status 1 (NodeJS)

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am getting this error while trying to copy a file from `S3` bucket to the build artifacts, post build.

My build phase error logs says:
**COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command:** `aws s3 cp "s3://bucket/config.json" "config.json". Reason: exit status 1`

Here's my BuildSpec:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
    - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - aws s3 cp "s3://bucket/config.json" "config.json"
```

Comment: Are there any more detail logs? Did you enable CloudWatch Logs for the CB project?

Comment: I will enable CloudWatch logs, re-run the build and post the logs in sometime. For now, I was wondering do we even have access to aws cli within the build spec file?

Comment: Yes, there is aws cli. One immediate thing that comes to mind, is if the CB role has permissions to access your s3 buckets and objects?

Comment: The issue was with the permissions! Thanks a ton, @Marcin. You can post it as the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was cased by CodeBuld role not having **permissions to S3**. Thus, to solve the issue, needed permissions to S3 were added to the role.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try adding the `--debug` flag to your aws cli command to get more information.

In this case:

```
aws s3 cp --debug "s3://bucket/config.json" "config.json"
```

This will show you more detail on where things are failing.